Help writing block matrix
I'm trying to transfer this block matrix to LaTeX:

Using the following code
\usepackage{nicematrix}[hvlines]
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}
\Block{2-2}{2s} & \Block{2-6}{0} \\
\Block{6-2}{0} & \Block{6-6}{2P}
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}

However, I'm getting the following error: "Package nicematrix Error: Block too large"
Does anyone know what is happening here?

Why do you use \Blocks at all? You just want to place things in cells, no need to use \Blocks. Did you read the manual of the package? Just use \[\begin{pNiceMatrix}[hvlines] 2s & 0 \\ 0 & 2P \end{pNiceMatrix}\] (and remove hvlines as package option).

Apologies if it wasn't clear in the picture. The matrix I'm trying to typeset has a 2S block matrix and a 2P block matrix with zeroes everywhere else. The 2P block matrix is supposed to be much bigger than the 2S block matrix (specifically the 2S block matrix is supposed to be a 2x2 matrix and the 2P block matrix is supposed to be 6x6, as indicated in the code). The reason I'm using the \Blocks is because it's important to indicate that 2P is bigger than 2S.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

A basic array environment gets the job done.

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\left( \begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
    2S & 0  \\ 
    \hline
    0  & 2P 
\end{array} \right)
\]

\end{document}


If you want to keep the proportions as in the picture
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  2S & 0 \\[0.5ex]
  \hline
  \\[-1.5ex]
  \mbox{\LARGE$0$} & \mbox{\LARGE$2P$}
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}



+1 for the large image size. :-)

Shouldn't the top right $0$ be a "\Large $0$" rotated through $90^\deg$?

@erstwhileeditor The readers' eyes would bleed.

If you really want to use \Blocks like this, you need to specify all empty cells (and rows):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}[hvlines]
\Block{2-2}{2s} & & \Block{2-6}{0} & & & & & \\ \\ 
\Block{6-2}{0} & & \Block{6-6}{2P} & & & & & \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}


